# more elegant way to set state

Tags: react-native, setstate

In the following function is there a more elegant or best practice way to setState?

```
startStop(){

   if(this.state.start === 'Start') startStop = 'Stop'
   else  startStop = 'Start'

   this.setState({start:startStop})

}
```

Comment: I think putting your curly brackets and your semicolons can be a huge step. [Great topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_EANG8ZZbRs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the flag, instead of string **Start/Stop** use true-false,

Eg:-

```
    constructor(props){
    this.state={
      start:false
      }
     }

    startStop(){
      this.setState({start:!this.state.start})
      }

render(){
  return<Text>{this.state.start?'Running':'Stopped'}</Text>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this.setState({start:this.state.start==='Start' ? 'Stop' : 'Start'})

Comment: no, that doesn't work as it won't toggle back and forth, but if we add === 'Start' we have a winner

Comment: Of course, forgot start wasn't a boolean. My bad

Answer (score 1):

If you had something like:

```
state = {
  keepGoing: false,
}
```

Then you could do the following to toggle:

```
this.setState({ keepGoing: !this.state.keepGoing });
```